# Cordova PhoneGap Floating Icon Android 5+ Samsung S6

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm currently building an App with Cordova/PhoneGap for IOS and Android.

I am having an issue with a floating Icon that appears on my Samsung S6 but not an Samsung S4. I've also tested the app on IOS devices and Asus Android 4.4.2 and it doesn't appear on those devices.

This is a movable floating icon like the android HALO project.

Does anyone know how to remove the floating Icon completely?

Here is the [link to the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFtuX.jpg) shot I took.

Comment: What does the icon look like? You can always upload an image to imgur and post the link here.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks!.  The icon is always on top. If you click it nothing happens. And you can drag it around.  It stays on top through out the entire app.
[imigur_link](http://imgur.com/a/nDukt)

Comment: If you are using CSS, then you need to test that CSS component first. DO NOT assume because it works on on device it will work on all.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Good advice! I learned that with trying to use flex box on IOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kyle for pointing me in the right direction.

To solve this issue, go to your androidconfig.xml and add the line

```
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

This will make that floating menu Icon go away.

value = "22" is targeting Android 5.1.1

I'm guessing that since I didn't specify what Android SDK to use it adds a menu button (Action Overflow button). On the Samsung S6 it overflows to a floating menu icon.

Answer (score 1):

I found this via a web search: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/513901-what-little-circle-three-dots-inside.html

Looks like you need to compile your app against the 5.0 SDK.