# Android 3 dotted button Galaxy S6

Tags: android

I'm working on a native Android app and I'm having a tough time trying to hide the 3 dotted button from my application.I've detected it on a client's Galaxy S6.

Here you can find a screenshot of the button and some more information about it, but, unfortunately, not a way to hide it: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/513901-what-little-circle-three-dots-inside.html.

I've also tried the solution from here: [Cordova PhoneGap Floating Icon Android 5+ Samsung S6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728027/cordova-phonegap-floating-icon-anroid-5-samsung-s6/31734031#31734031)

But everything was without success.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

i Think u just need to remove the `item` tag under the res/menu/yourfile.xml if not working just share your Code `XML` file

Answer (score 0):

> res-> menu-> your_menu_xml

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit_pass"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_edit_pass"/>
```

the 3rd line is the important: change the "never" to "always".

Answer (score 0):

The response from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728027/cordova-phonegap-floating-icon-anroid-5-samsung-s6/31734031#31734031) was right. The first time when I tried it I've selected the target SDK from Ecplise (right click on the project, etc...), but I failed to notice that android:targetSdkVersion was not added to my AndroidManifest.xml.

So in order to fix this I added manually android:targetSdkVersion="22" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```